# Yii multiple related model

Tags: php, yii, relationship

I need to make the ability to add a lot of addresses on the registration form. I used this [example](http://tahiryasin.wordpress.com/2013/05/06/how-to-save-multiple-related-models-in-yii-complete-solution/), but it displays an error:

```
Argument 4 passed to CClientScript::registerScript() must be of the type array, integer given, called in /var/www/yii/protected/views/user/_form.php on line 77 and defined
```

Part of user/_form.php

```
<div id="address">

</div>

<?php echo CHtml::link('Add Child', '#', array('id' => 'loadChildByAjax')); ?>

<?php
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('loadchild', '
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#loadChildByAjax").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var _url = "' . Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("loadChildByAjax"), '
            $.ajax({
                method: GET,
                url: _url,
                dataType: html,
                success:function(data){
                    $("#address").append(data);
                }
            });
        });
        });
    ', CClientScript::POS_END);
?>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
var _url = "' . Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("loadChildByAjax"), '
```

Should be

```
var _url = "' . Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("loadChildByAjax"). '";
```

i suppose.